# How to make sure the next line of code is not executed before the current line is done

Tags: c#, wait

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(lPath); 
DirectoryInfo dest = new DirectoryInfo(lPath9);
if (!dest.Exists) dest.Create(di.GetAccessControl());
string mapDirName = di.FullName;
di.Delete(true);
Thread.Sleep(20);  // let the process wait a bit       
dest.MoveTo(mapDirName);           
Thread.Sleep(20);  // let the process wait a bit
```

The above code works most of the time. However, sometime some sub-directories are missing after dest is renamed to di.

I think it is because the rename has started before the delete is complete.
I can add a while loop to check for the existence of di before I rename.
Such as,

```
int i=0;
While (di.Exists && i < 10) {
     Thread.Sleep(10000);
     i++;
}
```

Still it would only wait 10000*10 milliseconds. There is no sure way of doing it without getting into an infinite loop.

Comment: Why would a subsequent line of code (in the same thread) execute before the previous line "is complete" for blocking operations?

Comment: Also, what filesystem is being used? Local filesystems are [generally] *atomic* for create/move/rename/delete operations.

Comment: Ken, Thank you for pointing that out. I meant to do it but I was not aware of the meta post link you send me to. I did try to vote and accept an answer everytime. But it never quite work previously. I did thank the person who answer my questions everytime. Live and learn. I will read carefully the meta post link this time. Thanks

Comment: Ken, SO is so fast that I got my answer within 15 minutes most of the time. That explains why I was not able to vote the last couple of times. I went back and voted. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of waiting an arbitrary amount of time before moving the dest directory, why not loop through the files in the di directory?

```
foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
{
    File.Delete( file );
}

dest.MoveTo( mapDirName );
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess this is a no win situation. I want to make it fast to remove the directory instead of clearing out the files one at a time.

Comment: I don't see why doing it this way would be any slower than deleting the directory recursively, as in di.Delete(true);

Comment: Ignorance and superstition on my part. I will just do it file by file then.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation where I needed to make sure that everything was deleted before moving on. This is how I managed to get around it. Seems to be working so far

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(location);
while (dir.Exists)
{
    dir.Delete(true);
    dir = new DirectoryInfo(location);
}
```